# Google Map geocoder returns multiple results against a complete town name (with county, state)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

I have the following address:

"Chelsea, New York, NY, USA"

In the above address:

City = 'Chelsea'
County = "New York"
State = "NY"
Country = "USA"

When i pass this address to the Google's Geocoder API it returns multiple results, while i am expecting a single result because every part (name, county, state, country) of the town name is specified in the address.

Here is the code snippet:

(Assuming required files are already included)

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({ "address": "Chelsea, New York, NY, USA" }, function (results, status) {

                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  if (results.length == 1) {                       
                      // do something
                        }
                      else{
                         // do something
                        }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about the multiple results you are getting? Perhaps a link to the JSON response? Or a list of the `formatted_address` field values for each result? While I agree the address you provided should be unique, disambiguation is the likely problem. You might try **Viewport Biasing** or **Region Biasing** depending on your application ([Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)).

Comment: That is the expected behavior from the geocoder. I usualy pick the first result. Unless you provide an address that google can narrow down to a point, the results will reflect google's attempt to match your input to a given point. A town contains lots of points.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my  VB function snippet to parse address using Google API that implements to get single record from API output

```
'Get formatted address using Google Geocoding API
Public Function GetGoogleAddress(ByVal address1 As String, ByVal city As String, ByVal state As String) As Hashtable

    Dim addressxml As String = String.Empty
    Dim zipCode As String = String.Empty
    Dim m_hashTable As New Hashtable()
    m_hashTable.Clear()
    Try
        address1 = address1.Replace(" CR ", " County Road ")
        address1 = address1.Replace(" SR ", " State Road ")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        'Create an object of web client
        Dim wsClient As New WebClient()

        'Construct the URL concating the address values with it
        Dim zipcodeurl As String = "?address={0},+{1},+{2}&sensor=false"
        'Here in constructing the URL sensor(is required) indicates whether or not the geocoding request comes from a device with a location sensor.

        Dim url As String = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml" & zipcodeurl
        url = [String].Format(url, address1.Replace(" ", "+"), city.Replace(" ", "+"), state.Replace(" ", "+"))

        'Download the data in XML format as string by making a web request
        addressxml = wsClient.DownloadString(url)

        'Check if status is OK then proceed
        If addressxml.Contains("OK") Then

            'Check if postal_code section is there in the string then proceed
            If addressxml.Contains("postal_code") Then
                Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(addressxml)
                Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
                Dim node As XmlNode
                'Get the list of all address_companent nodes as this component only contans the address information
                'm_nodelist = node.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component")
                node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result")
                m_nodelist = node.SelectNodes("address_component")
                'From each component check for the type section for getting the particular postal_code section
                Dim gcount As Integer = 0 'Just to read first entry of google map
                For Each m_node In m_nodelist
                    If gcount < 1 Then
                        Try
                            'Get the zipLongName Element Value
                            Dim LongName = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText
                            'Get the zipShortName Element Value
                            Dim ShortName = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText
                            'Get the zipType Element Value
                            Dim Type = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText

                            'If the type of the component is postal_code then get the postal code as zipLongName
                            If Type = "street_number" Then
                                m_hashTable.Add("street_number", LongName)
                            End If

                            If Type = "route" Then
                                m_hashTable.Add("street", LongName)
                            End If

                            If Type = "locality" Then
                                m_hashTable.Add("city", LongName)
                            End If
                            If Type = "administrative_area_level_1" Then
                                m_hashTable.Add("state", ShortName)
                            End If
                            If Type = "postal_code" Then
                                zipCode = LongName
                                m_hashTable.Add("zip", LongName)
                            End If
                            gcount = gcount + 1
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
                        End Try
                    End If

                Next

            End If
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("No OK on XML or Over Quota")
        End If


    Catch ex As WebException

       Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())


    End Try

    Return m_hashTable


End Function
```

> Additional code snippets are on the blog:

http://gis-techniques.blogspot.com/2013/10/united-states-physical-address.html

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is Chelsea is not a 'city'

Chelsea is a neighborhood in the Borough of Manhattan, which is a 2nd level administrative division ( ~county) of New York City. Whether you are using Google or another geocoder, your geographic composition is:

Locality (neighborhood): Chelsea, Manhattan
County: New York 
City: New York
State: New York

Usual the locality can be put into the address component of a geocoder query.